# Converting 16-bit integer to 32-bit floating-point

Tags: python, integer, floating-point

I am trying to port a portion of a code written in a different language (an obscure one called Igor Pro by Wavemetrics for those of you have heard of it) to Python.

In this code, there is a conversion of a data type from a 16-bit integer (read in from a 16-bit, big endian binary file) to single-precision (32-bit) floating-point. In this program, the conversion is as follows:

Signed 16-bit integer:

```
print tmp
tmp[0]={-24160,18597,-24160,18597,-24160}
```

converted to 32-bit floating-point:

```
Redimension/S/E=1 tmp
print tmp
tmp[0]={339213,339213,5.79801e-41,0,0}
```

The `/S` flag/option indicates that the data type of `tmp` should be float32 instead of int16. However, I believe the important flag/option is `/E=1`, which is said to "Force reshape without converting or moving data."

In Python, the conversion is as follows:

```
>>> tmp[:5]
array([-24160,  18597, -24160,  18597, -24160], dtype=int16)

>>> tmp.astype('float32')
array([-24160.,  18597., -24160., ...,  18597., -24160.,  18597.], dtype=float32)
```

Which is what I expect, but I need to find a function/operation that emulates the `/E=1` option in the original code above. Is there an obvious way in which -24160 and 18597 would both be converted to 339213? Does this have anything to do with `byteswap` or `newbyteorder` or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy
tmp=numpy.array([-24160,18597,-24160,18597,-24160, 0], numpy.int16)
tmp.dtype = numpy.float32
print tmp
```

Result:

```
[  3.39213000e+05   3.39213000e+05   5.79801253e-41]
```

I had to add a zero to the list of value because there are an odd number of values. It cannot interpret those as 32 bit floats since there 5 16 bit values.

Answer (score 2):

Use [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) instead of [astype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
In [9]: tmp=np.array([-24160,  18597, -24160,  18597, -24160, 18597], dtype=int16)

In [10]: tmp.view('float32')
Out[10]: array([ 339213.,  339213.,  339213.], dtype=float32)
```

1. `.astype` creates a copy of the array cast to the new dtype
2. `.view` returns a view of the array (with the same underlying data),
   with the data interpreted according to the new dtype.

Comment: Thanks -- that is odd that the returned value from astype and the view operation prints different things...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an obvious way in which -24160 and 18597 would both be converted to 339213?

No, but neither is there any obvious way in which -24160 would convert to 339213 *and* 5.79801e-41 *and* 0.

It looks more like the conversion takes *two* input numbers to create *one* output (probably by concatenating the raw 2×16 bits to 32 bits and calling the result a float). In that case the pair `-24160,18597` consistently becomes 339213, and 5.79801e-41 probably results from `-24160,0` where the 0 is invented because we run out of inputs. Since 5.79801e-41 looks like it might be a single-precision denormal, this implies that the two 16-bit blocks are probably concatenated in little-endian order.

It remains to see whether you need to byte-swap each of the 16-bit inputs, but you can check that for yourself.